# varnish round robin director not picking backends

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have varnish setup with 2 backend servers with a round-robin director.

The 2 backends are showing up in varnishstat and varnishadm as healthy.

varnishadm output:

```
Backend name                   Admin      Probe
boot.app1                      probe      Healthy 5/5
boot.app2                      probe      Healthy 5/5
```

VCL Configuration:

```
probe ping {
  .interval = 5s;
  .timeout = 1s;
  .threshold = 3;
  .window = 5;
  .url = "/ping";
}
backend app1 {
  .host = "app-1.example.com";
  .port = "80";
  .probe = ping;
}

backend app2 {
  .host = "app-2.example.com";
  .port = "80";
  .probe = ping;
}

new application_servers = directors.round_robin();
application_servers.add_backend(app1);
application_servers.add_backend(app2);

set req.backend_hint = application_servers;
```

varnishstat output:

```
VBE.boot.app1.happy                                                                                                                        ffffffffff     VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
VBE.boot.app1.bereq_hdrbytes                                                                                                                    66.17K         0.00         91.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.app1.beresp_hdrbytes                                                                                                                   76.72K         0.00        106.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.app1.beresp_bodybytes                                                                                                                  11.91M         0.00         16.50K         0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.app1.conn                                                                                                                                251          0.00           .          251.00        251.00        251.00
VBE.boot.app1.req                                                                                                                                 251          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.app2.happy                                                                                                                        ffffffffff     VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
```

You can see from the varnishstat command that traffic appears to only be sent to the first server in the round-robin configuration. There's no other lines for the app2 server other than .happy

Any thoughts on what would be causing the director to pick the first server every time?

## Varnishstat -1 Output

```
MAIN.uptime             218639         1.00 Child process uptime
MAIN.sess_conn         5253150        24.03 Sessions accepted
MAIN.sess_drop               0         0.00 Sessions dropped
MAIN.sess_fail               0         0.00 Session accept failures
MAIN.client_req_400            0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 400 errors
MAIN.client_req_417            0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 417 errors
MAIN.client_req          1174495         5.37 Good client requests received
MAIN.cache_hit                61         0.00 Cache hits
MAIN.cache_hitpass           395         0.00 Cache hits for pass
MAIN.cache_miss             1927         0.01 Cache misses
MAIN.backend_conn              0         0.00 Backend conn. success
MAIN.backend_unhealthy            0         0.00 Backend conn. not attempted
MAIN.backend_busy                 0         0.00 Backend conn. too many
MAIN.backend_fail                 0         0.00 Backend conn. failures
MAIN.backend_reuse             7720         0.04 Backend conn. reuses
MAIN.backend_recycle           8926         0.04 Backend conn. recycles
MAIN.backend_retry                0         0.00 Backend conn. retry
MAIN.fetch_head                   0         0.00 Fetch no body (HEAD)
MAIN.fetch_length              1350         0.01 Fetch with Length
MAIN.fetch_chunked             7572         0.03 Fetch chunked
MAIN.fetch_eof                    3         0.00 Fetch EOF
MAIN.fetch_bad                    0         0.00 Fetch bad T-E
MAIN.fetch_none                   0         0.00 Fetch no body
MAIN.fetch_1xx                    0         0.00 Fetch no body (1xx)
MAIN.fetch_204                    0         0.00 Fetch no body (204)
MAIN.fetch_304                   27         0.00 Fetch no body (304)
MAIN.fetch_failed                 0         0.00 Fetch failed (all causes)
MAIN.fetch_no_thread              0         0.00 Fetch failed (no thread)
MAIN.pools                        2          .   Number of thread pools
MAIN.threads                     20          .   Total number of threads
MAIN.threads_limited              0         0.00 Threads hit max
MAIN.threads_created           1377         0.01 Threads created
MAIN.threads_destroyed         1357         0.01 Threads destroyed
MAIN.threads_failed               0         0.00 Thread creation failed
MAIN.thread_queue_len             0          .   Length of session queue
MAIN.busy_sleep                   3         0.00 Number of requests sent to sleep on busy objhdr
MAIN.busy_wakeup                  3         0.00 Number of requests woken after sleep on busy objhdr
MAIN.busy_killed                  0         0.00 Number of requests killed after sleep on busy objhdr
MAIN.sess_queued               1728         0.01 Sessions queued for thread
MAIN.sess_dropped                 0         0.00 Sessions dropped for thread
MAIN.n_object                   135          .   object structs made
MAIN.n_vampireobject              0          .   unresurrected objects
MAIN.n_objectcore               141          .   objectcore structs made
MAIN.n_objecthead               146          .   objecthead structs made
MAIN.n_waitinglist               17          .   waitinglist structs made
MAIN.n_backend                    6          .   Number of backends
MAIN.n_expired                  840          .   Number of expired objects
MAIN.n_lru_nuked                  0          .   Number of LRU nuked objects
MAIN.n_lru_moved                 52          .   Number of LRU moved objects
MAIN.losthdr                      0         0.00 HTTP header overflows
MAIN.s_sess                 5253150        24.03 Total sessions seen
MAIN.s_req                  1174495         5.37 Total requests seen
MAIN.s_pipe                       0         0.00 Total pipe sessions seen
MAIN.s_pass                    7025         0.03 Total pass-ed requests seen
MAIN.s_fetch                   8952         0.04 Total backend fetches initiated
MAIN.s_synth                1165482         5.33 Total synthethic responses made
MAIN.s_req_hdrbytes        58007743       265.31 Request header bytes
MAIN.s_req_bodybytes           8324         0.04 Request body bytes
MAIN.s_resp_hdrbytes      250174363      1144.23 Response header bytes
MAIN.s_resp_bodybytes     658785662      3013.12 Response body bytes
MAIN.s_pipe_hdrbytes              0         0.00 Pipe request header bytes
MAIN.s_pipe_in                    0         0.00 Piped bytes from client
MAIN.s_pipe_out                   0         0.00 Piped bytes to client
MAIN.sess_closed            1170177         5.35 Session Closed
MAIN.sess_closed_err        5244623        23.99 Session Closed with error
MAIN.sess_readahead               0         0.00 Session Read Ahead
MAIN.sess_herd                 3208         0.01 Session herd
MAIN.sc_rem_close              3518         0.02 Session OK  REM_CLOSE
MAIN.sc_req_close                 0         0.00 Session OK  REQ_CLOSE
MAIN.sc_req_http10          1165458         5.33 Session Err REQ_HTTP10
MAIN.sc_rx_bad                    0         0.00 Session Err RX_BAD
MAIN.sc_rx_body                   0         0.00 Session Err RX_BODY
MAIN.sc_rx_junk             4079015        18.66 Session Err RX_JUNK
MAIN.sc_rx_overflow               0         0.00 Session Err RX_OVERFLOW
MAIN.sc_rx_timeout              276         0.00 Session Err RX_TIMEOUT
MAIN.sc_tx_pipe                   0         0.00 Session OK  TX_PIPE
MAIN.sc_tx_error                  0         0.00 Session Err TX_ERROR
MAIN.sc_tx_eof                    0         0.00 Session OK  TX_EOF
MAIN.sc_resp_close             4688         0.02 Session OK  RESP_CLOSE
MAIN.sc_overload                  0         0.00 Session Err OVERLOAD
MAIN.sc_pipe_overflow             0         0.00 Session Err PIPE_OVERFLOW
MAIN.sc_range_short               0         0.00 Session Err RANGE_SHORT
MAIN.shm_records           92391706       422.58 SHM records
MAIN.shm_writes            24787122       113.37 SHM writes
MAIN.shm_flushes               4278         0.02 SHM flushes due to overflow
MAIN.shm_cont                 72956         0.33 SHM MTX contention
MAIN.shm_cycles                  30         0.00 SHM cycles through buffer
MAIN.backend_req               8952         0.04 Backend requests made
MAIN.n_vcl                        3         0.00 Number of loaded VCLs in total
MAIN.n_vcl_avail                  3         0.00 Number of VCLs available
MAIN.n_vcl_discard                0         0.00 Number of discarded VCLs
MAIN.bans                         1          .   Count of bans
MAIN.bans_completed               1          .   Number of bans marked 'completed'
MAIN.bans_obj                     0          .   Number of bans using obj.*
MAIN.bans_req                     0          .   Number of bans using req.*
MAIN.bans_added                   1         0.00 Bans added
MAIN.bans_deleted                 0         0.00 Bans deleted
MAIN.bans_tested                  0         0.00 Bans tested against objects (lookup)
MAIN.bans_obj_killed              0         0.00 Objects killed by bans (lookup)
MAIN.bans_lurker_tested            0         0.00 Bans tested against objects (lurker)
MAIN.bans_tests_tested             0         0.00 Ban tests tested against objects (lookup)
MAIN.bans_lurker_tests_tested            0         0.00 Ban tests tested against objects (lurker)
MAIN.bans_lurker_obj_killed              0         0.00 Objects killed by bans (lurker)
MAIN.bans_dups                           0         0.00 Bans superseded by other bans
MAIN.bans_lurker_contention              0         0.00 Lurker gave way for lookup
MAIN.bans_persisted_bytes               16          .   Bytes used by the persisted ban lists
MAIN.bans_persisted_fragmentation            0          .   Extra bytes in persisted ban lists due to fragmentation
MAIN.n_purges                                0          .   Number of purge operations executed
MAIN.n_obj_purged                            0          .   Number of purged objects
MAIN.exp_mailed                           2879         0.01 Number of objects mailed to expiry thread
MAIN.exp_received                         2879         0.01 Number of objects received by expiry thread
MAIN.hcb_nolock                           2383         0.01 HCB Lookups without lock
MAIN.hcb_lock                              975         0.00 HCB Lookups with lock
MAIN.hcb_insert                            975         0.00 HCB Inserts
MAIN.esi_errors                              0         0.00 ESI parse errors (unlock)
MAIN.esi_warnings                            0         0.00 ESI parse warnings (unlock)
MAIN.vmods                                   2          .   Loaded VMODs
MAIN.n_gzip                                  0         0.00 Gzip operations
MAIN.n_gunzip                             2945         0.01 Gunzip operations
MAIN.vsm_free                           972480          .   Free VSM space
MAIN.vsm_used                         83961104          .   Used VSM space
MAIN.vsm_cooling                          1024          .   Cooling VSM space
MAIN.vsm_overflow                            0          .   Overflow VSM space
MAIN.vsm_overflowed                          0         0.00 Overflowed VSM space
MGT.uptime                              218640         1.00 Management process uptime
MGT.child_start                              1         0.00 Child process started
MGT.child_exit                               0         0.00 Child process normal exit
MGT.child_stop                               0         0.00 Child process unexpected exit
MGT.child_died                               0         0.00 Child process died (signal)
MGT.child_dump                               0         0.00 Child process core dumped
MGT.child_panic                              0         0.00 Child process panic
MEMPOOL.busyobj.live                         0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.busyobj.pool                        10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.busyobj.sz_wanted                65536          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.busyobj.sz_actual                65504          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.busyobj.allocs                    8952         0.04 Allocations
MEMPOOL.busyobj.frees                     8952         0.04 Frees
MEMPOOL.busyobj.recycle                   8934         0.04 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.busyobj.timeout                   2477         0.01 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.busyobj.toosmall                     0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.busyobj.surplus                      0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.busyobj.randry                      18         0.00 Pool ran dry
MEMPOOL.req0.live                            0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.req0.pool                           10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.req0.sz_wanted                   65536          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.req0.sz_actual                   65504          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.req0.allocs                    2622296        11.99 Allocations
MEMPOOL.req0.frees                     2622296        11.99 Frees
MEMPOOL.req0.recycle                   2622295        11.99 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.req0.timeout                      1604         0.01 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.req0.toosmall                        0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.req0.surplus                         0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.req0.randry                          1         0.00 Pool ran dry
MEMPOOL.sess0.live                           0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.sess0.pool                          10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.sess0.sz_wanted                    512          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.sess0.sz_actual                    480          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.sess0.allocs                   2620824        11.99 Allocations
MEMPOOL.sess0.frees                    2620824        11.99 Frees
MEMPOOL.sess0.recycle                  2620823        11.99 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.sess0.timeout                     2001         0.01 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.sess0.toosmall                       0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.sess0.surplus                        0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.sess0.randry                         1         0.00 Pool ran dry
MEMPOOL.req1.live                            0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.req1.pool                           10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.req1.sz_wanted                   65536          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.req1.sz_actual                   65504          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.req1.allocs                    2633786        12.05 Allocations
MEMPOOL.req1.frees                     2633786        12.05 Frees
MEMPOOL.req1.recycle                   2633785        12.05 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.req1.timeout                      1589         0.01 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.req1.toosmall                        0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.req1.surplus                         0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.req1.randry                          1         0.00 Pool ran dry
MEMPOOL.sess1.live                           0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.sess1.pool                          10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.sess1.sz_wanted                    512          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.sess1.sz_actual                    480          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.sess1.allocs                   2632326        12.04 Allocations
MEMPOOL.sess1.frees                    2632326        12.04 Frees
MEMPOOL.sess1.recycle                  2632325        12.04 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.sess1.timeout                     1908         0.01 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.sess1.toosmall                       0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.sess1.surplus                        0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.sess1.randry                         1         0.00 Pool ran dry
SMA.s0.c_req                                93         0.00 Allocator requests
SMA.s0.c_fail                                0         0.00 Allocator failures
SMA.s0.c_bytes                          905611         4.14 Bytes allocated
SMA.s0.c_freed                          849277         3.88 Bytes freed
SMA.s0.g_alloc                               7          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.s0.g_bytes                           56334          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.s0.g_space                      6442394610          .   Bytes available
SMA.Transient.c_req                    2363316        10.81 Allocator requests
SMA.Transient.c_fail                         0         0.00 Allocator failures
SMA.Transient.c_bytes               2083208664      9528.07 Bytes allocated
SMA.Transient.c_freed               2083145488      9527.79 Bytes freed
SMA.Transient.g_alloc                      132          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_bytes                    63176          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_space                        0          .   Bytes available
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.happy 18446744073709551615          .   Happy health probes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.bereq_hdrbytes      1944414         8.89 Request header bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.bereq_bodybytes         8324         0.04 Request body bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.beresp_hdrbytes      1608040         7.35 Response header bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.beresp_bodybytes    154396823       706.17 Response body bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.pipe_hdrbytes               0         0.00 Pipe request header bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.pipe_out                    0         0.00 Piped bytes to backend
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.pipe_in                     0         0.00 Piped bytes from backend
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.conn                     4297          .   Concurrent connections to backend
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app1.req                      4297         0.02 Backend requests sent
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.happy            18446744073709551615          .   Happy health probes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.bereq_hdrbytes              0         0.00 Request header bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.bereq_bodybytes             0         0.00 Request body bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.beresp_hdrbytes             0         0.00 Response header bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.beresp_bodybytes            0         0.00 Response body bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.pipe_hdrbytes               0         0.00 Pipe request header bytes
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.pipe_out                    0         0.00 Piped bytes to backend
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.pipe_in                     0         0.00 Piped bytes from backend
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.conn                        0          .   Concurrent connections to backend
VBE.58b9f33d-bb8c-4540-ab9e-73da4e8c1cf9.app2.req                         0         0.00 Backend requests sent
LCK.backend.creat                                                         7         0.00 Created locks
LCK.backend.destroy                                                       0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.backend.locks                                                    194025         0.89 Lock Operations
LCK.backend_tcp.creat                                                     2         0.00 Created locks
LCK.backend_tcp.destroy                                                   0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.backend_tcp.locks                                                 34549         0.16 Lock Operations
LCK.ban.creat                                                             1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.ban.destroy                                                           0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.ban.locks                                                       1193862         5.46 Lock Operations
LCK.busyobj.creat                                                      8951         0.04 Created locks
LCK.busyobj.destroy                                                    8952         0.04 Destroyed locks
LCK.busyobj.locks                                                    227907         1.04 Lock Operations
LCK.cli.creat                                                             1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.cli.destroy                                                           0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.cli.locks                                                         72890         0.33 Lock Operations
LCK.exp.creat                                                             1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.exp.destroy                                                           0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.exp.locks                                                         17964         0.08 Lock Operations
LCK.hcb.creat                                                             1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hcb.destroy                                                           0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hcb.locks                                                          3030         0.01 Lock Operations
LCK.lru.creat                                                             2         0.00 Created locks
LCK.lru.destroy                                                           0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.lru.locks                                                          6675         0.03 Lock Operations
LCK.mempool.creat                                                         5         0.00 Created locks
LCK.mempool.destroy                                                       0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.mempool.locks                                                  22011020       100.67 Lock Operations
LCK.objhdr.creat                                                       1094         0.01 Created locks
LCK.objhdr.destroy                                                      947         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.objhdr.locks                                                    4780984        21.87 Lock Operations
LCK.pipestat.creat                                                        1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.pipestat.destroy                                                      0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.pipestat.locks                                                        0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.sess.creat                                                      5250338        24.01 Created locks
LCK.sess.destroy                                                    5252842        24.03 Destroyed locks
LCK.sess.locks                                                           11         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.smp.creat                                                             0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.smp.destroy                                                           0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.smp.locks                                                             0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.vbe.creat                                                             1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vbe.destroy                                                           0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vbe.locks                                                         72885         0.33 Lock Operations
LCK.vcapace.creat                                                         1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vcapace.destroy                                                       0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vcapace.locks                                                         0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.vcl.creat                                                             1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vcl.destroy                                                           0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vcl.locks                                                         33732         0.15 Lock Operations
LCK.vxid.creat                                                            1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vxid.destroy                                                          0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vxid.locks                                                         1348         0.01 Lock Operations
LCK.waiter.creat                                                          2         0.00 Created locks
LCK.waiter.destroy                                                        0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.waiter.locks                                                      43236         0.20 Lock Operations
LCK.wq.creat                                                              3         0.00 Created locks
LCK.wq.destroy                                                            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.wq.locks                                                       16545779        75.68 Lock Operations
LCK.wstat.creat                                                           1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.wstat.destroy                                                         0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.wstat.locks                                                     5362050        24.52 Lock Operations
LCK.sma.creat                                                             2         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sma.destroy                                                           0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sma.locks                                                       4726679        21.62 Lock Operations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue was related to the puppet module for deploying varnish.

The puppet module wasn't including the relevant template in the vcl file.

I've submitted a pull request to GitHub to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would call .backend() to pass at as the backend_hint.

```
req.backend_hint = application_servers.backend();
```

I would think that would be a syntax error to not do that, but it's possible that it simply returns the first backend in the case that you use the director instance as a backend.

Comment: The way I have implement it is the same as what's in the Varnish docs: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-backends.html#directors

Comment: But look at the last line: `set req.backend_hint = bar.backend();`

Comment: Tried changing this and it hasn't made any difference. All traffic is still going to the first app server

Comment: Perhaps a bit more of your sanitized configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Where in your vcl is the line `set req.backend.hint = application_servers.backend();` ?

It should be the first line in `sub vcl_recv`

Also, what does the probe window look like? You listed 'happy' but if you run `varnishstat -1` you should see the full probe window.

To help debug it further put in some syslog calls in your vcl. Use either vmod std or just inline them with

```
C{ 
  syslog(LOG_ERR, "I am at line X in my vcl");
}C
```

You need to turn-on inline C option. In Varnish 4 it defaults to off.